# Reading coordinate data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read coordinate into Databricks as follows:

```
00°00'0.00"N
```

However, when  read the data, I get the following output:

```
00?00'0.00"N
```

It returns back a question mark.

I have tried to replace the value, but this did not work as I received the following error:

> Dangling meta character '?' near index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is a special character in regex and you probably tried to replace the `?` using `regexp_replace`, which caused an error. You can instead try `replace` which interprets the string to be replaced as it is, not as a regex.

```
df2 = df.withColumn('col1', F.expr("replace(col1, '?', '°')"))
```